# Mac Software that Detects Windows Malware

Tags: windows, security, malware, virus, anti-virus

I want to use my Mac to scan drives that have Windows partitions on them for malware. I know that there are a lot of security software packages out there for Macs but I'm not sure if they detect Windows based malware to the same extent that a Windows security software package would. Does anyone out there have experience using their Macs to detect viruses on Windows partitions and/or external drives that may have been infected with Windows based malware? What software is the best for this?

Comment: We **always** recommend the `Malwarebytes` or `Combo Cleaner` app to my customers, including those in our company, **for people who have less experience with malware.**

Answer (score 2):

The antivirus tools I've used (Sophos and Malwarebytes) can scan for Windows viruses.

One issue that comes up is that typically macOS doesn't have write access to the bootcamp partition.

For external drives that macOS has write access to, the above tools had no problem identifying and quarantining suspected Windows malware.